# What is the output of this code? Am i missing something here?

Tags: c++, operators, increment, decrement

```
void main()
{
    int num, a=15; 
    num = ----a--;
    cout<<num;
    cout<<a;
 }
```

I tried it... I should get 
15
14
On paper, coz 4 minus cancel each other and what's left is a--

But on PC I get compile error coz the ---- before the a-- makes the compiler think there are pre/post decrement operators in this '----' and asks for an operand. What's the solution?

Comment: The solution is to not use such an obfuscated piece of code and clearly express what you want do.  Programming is hard enough why make it more difficult then it needs to be?

Comment: @NathanOliver no no actually this is exactly what was asked in a question paper

Comment: Why would `----` cancel each other out? `--` decrements, so I don't see why two of them would decrement and increment. Apart from that, when getting a compiler error, you should post the exact error in full, not try to describe it.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? There is some useful discussion that could be had about operator binding, lvalues etc.

Comment: The output is a compiler error. The content of the error depends on the compiler.

Comment: If the output on a PC is "compile error", there is no reason to trust your assessment of the output on paper either, because the correct output is no output at all.

Comment: @chris okay so the behave as a unary minus and not four times mathematical negations... but then it asks for an operand coz well after the     --    there is another     --    . why doesent the compiler interpret it as 4 times negation?

Comment: @NiranjanDixit It interprets it as two predecrements in a row because of maximum munch rule and gives an error, because you are trying to apply it to the r-value. Code in your post is illegal, and error is expected.

Comment: Start [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). And look at the [lvalue requirement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: @NiranjanDixit, Oh, now I see what you mean. It never occurred to me that you were interpreting it as unary minus. The last paragraph did not make that clear to me.

Comment: If you develop a taste for increment and decrement operators then there is always a programming language that [uses a lot of them](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83832/bfcat-encode-a-file-as-a-brainf-program).

Comment: @chris im so sorry i got confused between unary minus and pre- and post- decrement terminologies... post edited 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int num, a = 15; 
    num = ( ----a )--;

    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
13
12
```

The post-decrement operator has a higher priority than the pre-decrement operator and its result is `rvalue` that may not be changed.

This expression

```
----a--
```

is equivalent to

```
----( a-- )
```

and will not compile.

So you need to use parentheses to make the program to compile.

Take into account that a corresponding program written in C as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int num, a = 15; 
    num = ( ----a )--;

    printf( "%d\n", num );
    printf( "%d\n", a );

    return 0;
}
```

will not compile because the pre-decrement operator in C also returns rvalue and you may not apply the operator to rvalue.

Only the C++ program is valid.

Comment: but the thing is the unmodifed version (what ive typed) is exactly what was once asked in a previous year's exam. so the out of the program be written as "it wont produce o/p due to compile error"?

Comment: but the thing is the unmodifed version (what ive typed) is exactly what was once asked in a previous year's exam. so the out of the program be written as "it wont produce o/p due to compile error"?

Comment: @NiranjanDixit Yes, the original code will not compile.